# Make part of input[text] grey?

Tags: jquery, css, text, input, instant

You know how google instant, when they provide suggestions, the bit of the search field that they suggested turns grey, but the bit you typed is always black. Well I want to achieve the same effect with a similar system. How would I go about this?

Thanks, Fela

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663710/how-do-i-implement-autocomplete-without-using-a-dropdownlist) and the associated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZb9r/3/), that looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: are you referring to the dropdown list of google search suggestions or the textbox we are typing in. can you provide some snapshots?

Comment: Exelian, sorry about that, Coding-Freak, I was referring to the text box, but I think the problem's solved now :)

Comment: thanks, I'll try that if the grey background input doesn't work. Cheers!

Comment: It uses exactly the same method as Curt suggested, so it'll definitely work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need 2 textboxes positioned on top of each other. Make the textbox on top have a transparent background (these will be the selectable textbox). Then set the color of the textbox behind to grey (this will be the textbox displaying the suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

You don't,
If you look closely to the Google Instant, you'll see that they have a  element positioned exactly where the inputbox is.
So to make it simple: Just position a div where your inputfield is. Then like so:

```
<div>
<span class="originaltext">hello</span>
</span class="suggested">world</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a grey `background-image` and adjusting its `background-position` property