# How to emulate Google greyed-out suggested text in input element?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how to do something like this in CSS:[image]

How is it possible to change the text color halfway through like that on an `<input>` tag ? I've done a View Source already, but it's hard to make sense of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement Autocomplete without using a Dropdownlist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663710/how-do-i-implement-autocomplete-without-using-a-dropdownlist)

Comment: Hmm, that's using two input boxes to 'fake' it. I suppose it would work but is there not a better way ?

Comment: @mikel, they are actually using a large number of divs to fake it. Even the blinking cursor is a black div with width of 1px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google uses two divs which are absolutely positioned on top of the input box. The first div contains the word stackoverflow, and the text is styled in a light gray. The second dvi contains "stacko" and the text is black.

If you inspect the source, look for divs with class="gsfi".

Comment: Thanks, I get the general idea of it now.

Answer (score 0):

First off, look into implementing autocompletion. This should give you another element [beneath the one the user types; probably another div] for styling.

Answer (score 0):

its not purely a CSS thing, you need JS too.

Have a look at this autocomplete demo: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Now you could use CSS for styling text selections in that input to gray the text out.

like this:

```
::selection {
color: white;
background-color: red;
}

::-moz-selection {
color: white;
background-color: red;
}
```