# Form Analyzation and Suggestions

Tags: forms, validation

I was filling out a form on uSell.com to ship out an old phone and when I entered my address, a dialog box popped up telling me what I entered along with their suggestion of what to change it to. I thought this was cool and was wondering how I can replicate that in my forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you talking about some kind of auto-completer. This can be done in various ways, depending on the languages you are using. You can make a simple auto-completer using just html, javascript and css. More complicated auto-completers can make server side calls to search through a database etc.

Have a look at the link below, they explain a very simple auto-completer.

[Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663710/how-do-i-implement-autocomplete-without-using-a-dropdownlist)

Hope this helps, good luck :)